# Materialize Select dropdown inside a Dropdown element

Tags: select, dropdown, materialize

I'm currently working with Materialize 1.0.0-rc.2 and I'm facing a problem. I got to know that the select box is now converted into a select dropdown, just similar to the dropdowns. As we know that one dropdown closes the other dropdown. So if I try to open a select box placed inside a dropdown, it closes the parent dropdown. In earlier version (0.98), this wasn't the case and it worked just perfectly. Can anyone help me with a solution?

```
<button id="dropdown-button-ex"
        class="dropdown-trigger btn-floating btn-large transparent waves-effect waves-light"
        data-target="MenuList">
        <i class="blue-grey-text material-icons">menu</i>
</button>

<ul class="dropdown-content" id="MenuList">
  <li>
    <div class="input-field">
        <select id="View1">
            <option value="" selected disabled>Select Name</option>
            <option value="Name1">Name1</option>
            <option value="Name2">Name2</option>
            <option value="Name3">Name3</option>
        </select> <label for="View1">Name</label>
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, when you click on select box, dropdown close by default and select box disappear also. Here is a solution to solve this problem :

When you open a dropdown, a `<ul>` appears with these styles :

```
.open {
   display: block; 
   width: 100px; 
   left: 0px; 
   top: 0px; 
   height: 81px; 
   transform-origin: 0px 0px 0px; 
   opacity: 1; 
   transform: scaleX(1) scaleY(1); 
}
```

So you can define a class with these css properties and add it to dropdown after click on selectbox :

```
$('input.select-dropdown').on("click",function(){
        $("ul#MenuList").addClass("open");
});
```

Also you should remove class after selecting an item in selectbox :

```
$('ul.dropdown-content li span').on("click",function(){
        $("ul#MenuList").removeClass("open");
});
```

It was more clear that materializecss did something like this and add a class to html element but they add styles directly to html element.

Here is complete solution : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vg2u4krb/69/)

Answer (score 0):

Nope. The solution given by @bahman parsamanesh doesn't work fine. When clicked on select box, the dropdown disappears and reappears. I tried a solution but it is not totally feasible. What I did while initializing my dropdown, as described at https://materializecss.com/dropdown.html, is shown below -

```
var elem = document.getElementById("dropdown-button-ex");
var instances = M.Dropdown.init( elem, {
            closeOnClick: false,
            outDuration: 0,
            inDuration: 0,
            onCloseEnd: function( dropdownEl ) {
                var temp = jQuery( '#MenuList .dropdown-content' );
                for ( var i = 0; i < temp.length; i++ ) {
                    var selectDropdown = temp[i];
                    var display = selectDropdown.style.display;
                    if ( display == "block" ) {
                        var dropdownElem = M.Dropdown.getInstance( elem );
                        dropdownElem.open();
                    }
                }
            }
} );
```

The above code works just fine for me. The dropdown does disappear and reappears when clicked on select. But as I have set 'inDuration' and 'outDuration' as 0, it happens so fast that the user does not know that it actually closed. But my trick, even though works, isn't right, is it? I need a proper solution.